# Move whole html content of a page down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, css-position

I want to insert a header in a page using javascript. I don't want to hide anything from the original content but just to add a header above that is fixed. Have in mind I don't know the content of the page I'm trying to manipulate.

I tried adding a margin-top to the body element:

```
body{
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

But if there are any elements with fixed position:

```
.header{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
}
```

They will remain on top of the page.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Adding a margin to the top won't work as your header will be in the body itself try to add padding instead. Or for a better practice create a blank div and give it default height and use it on the top of the page.

Comment: maybe try using position relative? or inefficiently, you can mark all position fixed elements with a unique class, and find and iterate throughout all elements using javascript, though it will be slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was to iterate over the elements and find out those with fixed position.

```
function moveDownFixedElements(){
let elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (let i = 0; i < elems.length ; i++) {
    if (window.getComputedStyle(elems[i], null).getPropertyValue('position') === 'fixed') {
        let style = window.getComputedStyle(elems[i]);
        let top = style.getPropertyValue('top');
        top = parseInt(top) + 40 + "px";
        elems[i].style.top = top; 
    }
}
}
```

Now without knowing the structure of the page I am able to insert something on top of it.

EDIT: 
Another really simple solution is to use the transform property.

```
document.body.style.transform = "translateY(40px)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
body{
  padding-top: 40px;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Not working for the elements with fixed position. They remain stick to the top.

Comment: Change top: 0, to top: 40px on the fixed position element then :)

Comment: As I have mentioned I don't know the content of the page. There could be many elements with fixed position. I should programatically iterate over them and change the top ?